# How much time google takes to approve Shareable data types?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am developing a Health application where i am using Google Fit to track my health related data. I want to know how much time Google takes to approve "Shareable data types" for my application? 

To know more.. [click here](http://www.wareable.com/google/how-to-use-google-fit-get-set-with-the-android-fitness-platform)

Comment: did you ask them?  Try the G+ Google Fit developers community https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103314459667402704958 as a first place to ask as the developers do monitor it.  The only sharable types I know of were there before release so very few people will of gone through the process.